# Surjecting a space with no cut point onto a cut-point space

Tags: general-topology

Can you give examples of connected spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that

(i) $X$ has no cut points

(ii) every point of $Y$ is a cut point

(iii) there is a continuous surjection $f:X\to Y$.

Is it possible for $Y=\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes $Y=\mathbb R$ should work. For $X$, what spaces can you remove a point and have them still be path  connected? Many should work, and these should not be difficult to come up with.

For the continuous surjection, I recommend finding a space $Y$ so that

$Y=\mathbb R \times Z$ that has the desired property of no cut points and choosing a surjection $\pi: \mathbb R \times Z\to X$ so that $\pi(x,z)=x$.

Answer (score 0):

X,Y are empty. X,Y are single point.

Y is any kind of interval of R and X is a product of
Y and connected spaces, at least one being multipoint.

Instead of R, one could use the long line, or even longer lines.